# How to Stamp PDF with another PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to capture page pdf and stamp to another pdf. 
Now I have the itextsharp library but I have some question about how to get capture page pdf by pass to this library.

Comment: Do you want to superimpose one PDF page on another PDF document, or do you want to insert one PDF page into another PDF document? The quality of your question is low in its current form. Please improve it by explaining what you've already tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "stamp to another pdf"? Do you want to append the pdfs?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My question is I have a pdf 2 file by pdf first have a one page and second pdf is a one page same, but I want to copy first page in second pdf (CapturedPage) and add to first page in first pdf. This Example.

Comment: Example. http://www.verious.com/qa/stamp-a-pdf-with-another-pdf-alternative-to-aspose-pdf-kit-39-s-pdf-file-stamp-class/

Comment: stamp meant to capture a PDF page and draw it onto another PDF.

Comment: I Found it http://t935.codeinpro.us/q/5081259f4f1eba38a4172911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, that you want to have a background pdf, and "stamp" another page onto this, try the following:

```
var backgroundDocument = PdfReader.Open("Background.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
var backgroundPage = backgroundDocument.Pages.Cast<PdfPage>().First();

var document = new PdfDocument();
var page = document.AddPage(backgroundPage);
```

Comment: FYI: The above is using PdfSharp, not iTextSharp.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. but I want to stamp to first page in pdf More than one stamp. this Example http://www.verious.com/qa/stamp-a-pdf-with-another-pdf-alternative-to-aspose-pdf-kit-39-s-pdf-file-stamp-class/